# Scheme procedure to compute the nth repeated application of a function?

Tags: function, scheme

Is anyone familiar with this?

> Write a procedure that takes as inputs
>   a procedure that computes f and a
>   positive integer n and returns the
>   procedure that computes the nth
>   repeated application of f. The
>   procedure should be able to be used as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> ((repeated square 2) 5)
> 625
> ```

I know that the following code I've created for the composition of functions will help make the solution simpler, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
(define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably want something like this, right?

```
((repeated square 3) 5)
-> (square ((repeated square 2) 5))
-> (square (square ((repeated square 1) 5)))
-> (square (square (square ((repeated square 0) 5))))
-> (square (square (square (identity 5))))
```

(I don't know whether `identity` is predefined in Scheme.  If not, it's easy to write.)

Now, this is not directly reproducible because you can't magically enclose code outside of the call to `repeated` with arbitrary stuff.  However, what do these reduction steps look like when rewritten using `compose`?  Can you make out a pattern in the resulting list of steps and reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
    identity
    (lambda (x) ((repeated f (- n 1)) (f x)))))
```

or, if you insist on using "compose":

```
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (zero? n)
    identity
    (compose (repeated f (- n 1)) f)))
```