# How to create a list with n applications of a procedure

Tags: list, racket

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249374/scheme-procedure-to-compute-the-nth-repeated-application-of-a-function) but in my case I would like to obtain a list with the results of n applications of a function whose output is not computable again with the previous result (picking randomly an element from a list, for example).

That is, it is **not** the composition of a function n times with itself but the n results shown together into a list.

Comment: Or `(define (f p n) (for/list ([i n]) (p)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!racket/base
(require srfi/1)

(define (times/list proc n)
  (unfold-right zero? proc sub1 n))

(times/list (lambda (v) (abs (- v 5))) 10)
; ==> (4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5)

(times/list (lambda _ 5) 10)
; ==> (5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)

(times/list (lambda _ (+ 1 (random 5))) 10)
; ==> (4 2 2 4 4 1 5 3 1 3) (varies)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Flist#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) like this:

```
(define (times/list proc n)
  (for/list ([i n]) (proc)))
```

Using it:

```
> (times/list (λ () (random 5)) 10)
'(3 4 3 3 0 0 4 0 2 1)
```